# Pascal Syntax Error in line

Tags: syntax-error, pascal

```
PROGRAM FactorPrimo(input,output);
VAR
    numero : integer;
    factor : integer;
    resto : integer;
    primo : integer;
    multiplicidad : boolean;

BEGIN
    write('Ingrese numero: ');
    readln(numero);
    factor := 2;
    primo := 0;
    multiplicidad := false;
    IF numero > 1 THEN
    BEGIN
        REPEAT
        BEGIN
            resto := numero MOD factor;
            IF resto = 0 THEN
            BEGIN
                numero := numero DIV factor;
                primo := primo + 1;
                multiplicidad := true;
            END
            ELSE IF multiplicidad = true THEN
                IF primo > 1 THEN
                writeln(factor,'^',primo);
                multiplicidad := false;
                ELSE
                writeln(factor);
                multiplicidad := false;
            ELSE
            factor := factor + 1;
            primo := 0;
            END;
        UNTIL numero = 1
        writeln(factor);
    END
    ELSE 
        write('Debe ingresar un numero mayor a 1');
END.
```

**Hello sorry for bothering you, I previusly made this code for java and now was traying to translate it to pascal, but i cant figured it out why it says i have a syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found in line (30,5).
Can you help me please?**

Comment: You need to surround the code after your `else` with `begin` and `end`

Answer (score 0):

Line 30 is an `ELSE` statement. The `IF` just above that has two lines of code between the else and if. Any time you have more than one line between an if and else, you must have a begin/end block. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Declarations_and_Statements#If_Statements

Change your code to

```
IF primo > 1 THEN BEGIN
  writeln(factor,'^',primo);
  multiplicidad := false;
END ELSE BEGIN
  writeln(factor);
  multiplicidad := false;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by puting a semicolon in:

```
UNTIL numero = 1;
```